# Stop service without reboot when FailureAction=reboot is defined

Tags: systemd

I have following service, which run java my java app. There is no ExecStop defined, therefore calling `systemctl stop garage` kills the app and app enters into FAILED state. But then, of course, reboot (`FailureAction=reboot`) is performed and rpi is rebooted.

I have 2 questions:

1) Is there any change to stop such service over e.g. systemctl without commenting out line "`FailureAction=`" and performing `daemon-reload` to avoid restart after stopping the service manually?

2) this also brings problem, when `shutdown` is called. Systemd stops my service, which enters into failed state, and instead of shutdown, rpi is rebooted, so shutdown operation is "interrupted". Any change to call shutdown without modification as in question 1)?

I was looking for some tip on the Internet, but was not successful.

garage.service

```
[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
ExecStart=/usr/java/default/bin/java -Xms150m -Xmx150m \
-Djava.library.path=/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib:/usr/local/src/openalpr/src/bindings/java:/home/pi/compile/raspicam-0.1.3/src/jni/:/home/pi/
-jar /home/pi/garageSystem.jar eu /home/pi/alpr.conf /usr/local/src/openalpr/runtime_data/ /home/pi/conf/

Restart=always
RestartSec=1
WatchdogSec=60


FailureAction=reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo systemctl kill garage`

I was looking for the same answer and this did it for me.